# Connecting to DB2 with SSL using Pyspark

Tags: ssl, pyspark, db2

I am trying to connect to DB2 with SSL using Pyspark on Linux. I tried the following

```
user = "xxxx"
password = "xxxxx"
jdbcURL = "jdbc:db2://nn.nn.nnn.nnn:nnnn/<database>"
prop = {"user": user, "password": password, "driver": 
"com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver", "sslConnection": "true"}
table = "<schema>.<table name>"
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcURL, table=table, properties=prop)
```

I also tried

```
user = "xxxx"
password = "xxxxx"
jdbcURL = "jdbc:db2://nn.nn.nnn.nnn:nnnn/<database>"
prop = {"user": user, "password": password, "driver": 
"com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver", "sslConnection": "true"
"Security": "SSL", "SSLServerCertificate": "<path to arm file>"}}
table = "<schema>.<table name>"
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcURL, table=table, properties=prop)
```

I get the same error in both cases
or socket output stream.

> Error location: Reply.fill() - socketInputStream.read (-1).  Message:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target. ERRORCODE=-4499,
>   SQLSTATE=08001

I am not sure of the syntax to specify the .arm path. Stuck. Please help

Ganesh

P.S. I can connect with python and ibm_db module using

```
import ibm_db
conn = ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=<database> 
;HOSTNAME=nn.nn.nnn.nnn:nnnn;SECURITY=SSL;SSLServerCertificate=<path to arm 
file> ;UID=<user>;PWD=<password>","","")
```

This works.

Comment: Edit your question to specify the Db2-server *version* and platform (z/os , i-series, linux/unix/windows).   Also specify your Db2-client (which supplies the Db2 jdbc driver) *version and fixpack*

Comment: Also, have you configured your JRE  correctly for SSL ?  Follow docs at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_t0054066.html

Comment: I am able to connect to SSL with python using ibm_db module. So the configuration is fine

Comment: ibm_db module uses CLI (no java) , but pySpark uses JDBC , So  *DIFFERENT RULES*, your configuration is suspect.

Comment: @mao, what is the syntax for connecting to DB2 with SSL using Pyspark?

Comment: Should be the like any jdbc application setup for Db2 TLS. It's not only the URL syntax, there's setup for the java keystore, jre config, cert import etc. All of this is adequately covered in the documentation at the URL I gave in a previous comment AND related pages.  Here is an example of a URL for the type-4 driver (db2jcc4.jar), connecting from linux to a remote Db2-server: `jdbc:db2://somehostname:50443/sample:sslConnection=true;sslKeyStoreLocation=/home/user1/.keystore;sslKeyStorePassword=secret`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by re-installing the Java certificate.